# How to destroy components in mat-stepper

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-stepper

I have some problems with my `mat-stepper`, where each step is a new component.

My problem is that `ngOnDestroy()` is not being triggered on each steps (components), when going back and forth in my `mat-stepper`.

My stepper is as follows:
HTML:

```html
<mat-horizontal-stepper [selectedIndex]="selectedIndex" linear labelPosition="bottom" #stepper fxLayoutAlign="center center" fxLayout="column">
    <mat-step [stepControl]="step1">
        <ng-template matStepLabel>{{ stepCaptions[0] }}</ng-template>
        <app-step1></app-step1>
    </mat-step>
    <mat-step [stepControl]="step2">
        <ng-template matStepLabel>{{ stepCaptions[1] }}</ng-template>
        <app-step2></app-step2>
    </mat-step>
    <mat-step [stepControl]="step3">
        <ng-template matStepLabel>{{ stepCaptions[2] }}</ng-template>
        <app-step3></app-step3>
    </mat-step>
    <mat-step [stepControl]="step4">
        <ng-template matStepLabel>{{ stepCaptions[3] }}</ng-template>
        <app-step4></app-step4>
    </mat-step>
    <mat-step [stepControl]="step5">
        <ng-template matStepLabel>{{ stepCaptions[4] }}</ng-template>
        <app-step5></app-step5>
    </mat-step>
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

Typescript:

```js
@ViewChild('stepper', { static: false }) stepper;
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: This is the common behavior. All Components are already initialized when the stepper is on its inital step

Comment: So I can't somehow "reload"/"recreate" each component

Comment: Sure you can, but its on your own how to do it. Maybe try to use "selectionChanged" to initialize / destroy your components.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `*ngIf` with the selectedIndex on your components to force `ngOnDestroy()` on your app-step components.

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper [selectedIndex]="selectedIndex" linear labelPosition="bottom" #stepper fxLayoutAlign="center center" fxLayout="column">
    <mat-step [stepControl]="step1">
        <ng-template matStepLabel>{{ stepCaptions[0] }}</ng-template>
        <app-step1 *ngIf="selectedIndex === 0"></app-step1>
    </mat-step>
    ...
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

Comment: So if the value of "selectedIndex" is turning into another value than 0, then the step1 component is going to be destroyed?

Comment: Yes so you should probably use the `selectionChange` output of mat-stepper to update your selectedIndex.

Answer (score 1):

Closely related -- and maybe helpful to some -- is the [`MatStepContent`](https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/api#MatStepContent) directive.

It will lazy load the contents only when the stepper progresses to that step.

*NOTE*: This directive does **not** affect the unloading/destruction of any nodes it affects.

```html
<mat-stepper>

    <mat-step label="Eagerly loaded contents">
        This will load immediately when the component loads.
    </mat-step>

    <mat-step label="Lazy loaded contents">
        <ng-template matStepContent>
            This text and image will only load once the user first visits step two.
            <img src="/img/blerg.png" />
        </ng-template>
    </mat-step>

    <mat-step label="Eagerly loaded contents">
        This will also load immediately when the component loads.
    </mat-step>

</mat-stepper>
```